# Custom login + auth Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

Using **Laravel 5.8**.

I have one table: `persons(id, matricule, name, section, is_punished, created_at, updated_at)`.

I have 4 page: `login_page`, `user_page`, `member_page`, and `not_member_page`.

### Desired result:

Allow the user to connect to any of the pages above and authenticate using only the `person` table and `matricule` column *note: matricule is French for "registration number".

The matricule column of the person table is populated by user input via a form at `login_page`, after which the user is authenticated and redirected to the `user_page`.

The redirect should be contingent on the matricule column.

Comment: Hi.  Your question is probably asking for too much.  You should make a competent attempt before asking questions and then show your attempt here.  People will be very reluctant to do spoon feeding and down-vote questions that request spoon feeding.  You're asking for something that exists in many forms throughout the internet and is easy to re-create by following tutorials or reading examples.  So, your question also might be considered chatty (and get a vote to close).  You just want a standard login form with authentication for 5.8 (maybe not a duplicate).  Leaving open, regardless.  +1 GL.

Comment: Hi. thank for your instruction , 
I think I try to improve my code and back here

Comment: I have followed basic instruction inside laravel doc to refresh my mind and it work but now I need to go back to my real project and i don't know where to start no doc or tutorial showed or helped me about my problen ,

Comment: There are various guides.  What's your distro?  Add it to the question body, please: https://dev.to/sujithjr/laravel-custom-authentication-system-4e1a

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Thank you for the link , I have already followed this tutorial and I understand it, but it doesn't really help me in about what I want to do
I don't use linux for now but i planned to switch in soon but i use windows10
As I said in my question I do not want to use user table/model, I just want to be able to log when i use
       ` if (Auth::attempt($request->matricule)) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        } `

Comment: Aka Dev, You should install Windows Linux Subsystem in Windows.  It's fantastic.  Also, consider getting a remote Linux Server (paying for one over the internet).